# How to perform clicking on the first item in an ArrayList by Espresso

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, android-espresso

I have tried to click on the first item of my arraylist for few hours, I have read a lot of questions on Stack Overflow, tutorials and I have tried to implement them in many ways, but it doesn't work.

```
   clickView(getSearchActivity().hintListView);

onData(anything())
    .onChildView(withId(R.id.hintLayout))
    .atPosition(0)
    .perform(click());

onData(allOf(is(instanceOf(String.class))))
    .atPosition(0)
    .perform(click());

onData(instanceOf(ArrayList.class))
    .atPosition(0)
    .perform(click());

onData(instanceOf(String.class))
    .atPosition(0)
    .perform(click());

onData(anything())
    .inAdapterView(withId(R.id.hintLayout))
    .atPosition(0)
    .perform(click());

onData(anything())
    .inAdapterView(allOf(withId(R.id.hintLayout), isCompletelyDisplayed()))
    .atPosition(0).perform(click());
```

I have to click on the first item of the ListView, that take ArrayList
id of this ListView is hintLayout.

Does anybody know what is the problem ? and where can it be ?

Comment: are you using  `ListView` or `RecyclerView` ?

Comment: I am using ListView

Comment: When I have to click item in Spinner it was enough to use: 
`onData(instanceOf(String.class))
        .atPosition(1).perform(click());`

now I have big struggle

Comment: I'm not clear on what you are trying to do. You wrote **I have to click on the first item of the ListView**. Does that mean you MUST click on the first element -- because your hard coding the position with `.atPosition(0).perform(click());`

Comment: I have to click on any element (no matter which one) but any of position can't be clicked - that's the problem.

Comment: I hope I understood what you are needing. Please have a look at my answer below.

Comment: Did my answer help you with a solution??

Comment: unfortunatelly not. in this case refactoring from list view to recycler view has helped

Answer (score 0):

A `ListView` must be filled with an adapter.  After your adapter is finished just add it to your `ListView` like this:

```
private void setListAdapter(ListDataAdapter adapter){
    lvYourListView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

In order to get the data back out on the `OnClick` event you need to something like this in you `onCreate()` method:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

 lvYourListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvListview);
        lvYourListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                ListData data = new ListData();

                data = (ListData)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

                doSomethingWithData(data);

            }
        });
```

If you need help with the adapter - just let me know. I will need to see more of your code in order to do that.